# ngResource causes website to crash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, crash, angularjs-resource

I have a webapplication using angular.js with ngResource module to use the REST API on the server.

Here's how all the different urls are accessed:

```
this.getSomething = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $resource(myConstants.API_BASE_URL + 'get/something', {}, {
        get: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: false,
            cache: false
        }
    }).get({}, function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

I think this is causing my browser tab to crash (tested on other browsers, they crash as well eventually, firefox displays javascript crash error).

Screenshot of the profiler:
[Profiler screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZOWl.png) (can't embed images yet :( )

Comment: You can do a step through using F10 and see if there is a recursion in this somewhere. Using tool like Chrome Dev tools or Firebug.